# How to debug Parser Error in solidity in my smart contract

Tags: constructor, solidity

So i am trying to create a smart contract for decentralized movie ratings using remix IDE. Here are the things I want to achieve:

1. Create a mapping field to store the movie reviews
2. Use an array to store the list of movies
3. Create a function that returns the total ratings a movie has received so far
4. Develop a constructor that will be called once you deploy the contract on Blockchain

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^ 0.8.10; 

contract Rating { 

    mapping (bytes32 => uint8) public ratingsReceived;

    bytes32 [] public movieList; 
    
    constructor Rating(bytes32[]movieNames) public { 
        movieList = movieNames;
    }
    function totalVotesFor(bytes32 movie) view public returns (uint8) {
        return ratingsReceived[movie]; 
    } 

    function voteForMovie(bytes32 movie) public { 
        ratingsReceived[movie];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check this contract i think it should be similar to what you are looking for https://github.com/Shahroozism/MovieRatingsonEthereum/blob/master/rating.sol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below code if it helps for movie rating contract with constructor and used mapping to store ratings and also we can add more movies as we required.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.7; 

contract Rating{

    string[] moviesList;

    mapping(string => uint8) movieRatings;

    constructor() {
        moviesList = ["movie1","movie2","movie3"]; // this is default list of movies you can add in constructor 
    }

    // add movies
    function addMovie(string memory movie) public returns(string memory){
        moviesList.push(movie);
        return movie;
    }

    // get list of movies
    function getList() public view returns(string[] memory){ 
        return moviesList;
    }

    // rate movie with rating
    function rateMovie(string memory movie,uint8 rating) public {
        require(rating >=0 && rating <= 10,"rating is out of range");
        movieRatings[movie] = rating;
    }
    
    // get movie rating by passing movie name
    function getMovieRating(string memory movie) public view returns(uint8){
        return movieRatings[movie];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to successfully compile it.

Comment: Hello @OlumideLawal Please mark this answer as correct if it helpful. Thanks